# Android SQLite Double variable giving garbage data on fetch

Tags: android

I have a table defined as this

```
String currencyTableQueryString = "create table if not exists "
            + CURRENCY_NAME + " (" + CURRENCY_ROW_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
            + CURRENCY_USD + " double," + CURRENCY_INR + " double,"
            + CURRENCY_EUR + " double," + CURRENCY_GBP + " double"
            + ");";
```

i store data in this table from a JSON.
As an example, i have stored this data

```
CURRENCY_USD = 1.0
CURRENCY_INR = 53.997369
CURRENCY_EUR = 0.764879
CURRENCY_GBP = 0.658136
```

In my next activity, i am fetching this data from the DB

```
Ccursor = db.query(CURRENCY_NAME, new String[] { CURRENCY_ROW_ID, CURRENCY_USD, CURRENCY_INR,
            CURRENCY_EUR, CURRENCY_GBP }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I ALWAYS get the wrong data when i fetch. It gives me very HIGH numbers in all my fields. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. (P.S. i am new to Java and Android programming).

this was the output from the fetch when the above numbers were inserted

```
CURRENCY_USD = 1.072693248E9
CURRENCY_INR = -1.0925335E8
CURRENCY_EUR = -1.80473634E8
CURRENCY_GBP = 9.1173113E7
```

Can someone please guide me to what is going wrong here?

This is my fetch cursor.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

    Cursor Ccursor;

    try {
        // ask the database object to create the cursor.
        Ccursor = db.query(CURRENCY_NAME, new String[] { CURRENCY_ROW_ID, CURRENCY_USD, CURRENCY_INR,
                CURRENCY_EUR, CURRENCY_GBP }, null, null, null, null, null);

        // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
        Ccursor.moveToFirst();

        // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
        // to the ArrayList.
        if (!Ccursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                dataList.add(Ccursor.getLong(0));
                dataList.add(Ccursor.getDouble(1));
                dataList.add(Ccursor.getDouble(2));
                dataList.add(Ccursor.getDouble(3));
                dataList.add(Ccursor.getDouble(4));

                dataArrays.add(dataList);
            }
            // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
            while (Ccursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Ccursor.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("DB Error in Currency Retreive all", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you adding this line if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst(); after getting data through cursor

Comment: Yes, i have updated my question with my fetch query.

Answer (score 0):

You can Export database from ddms view data - data  to desktop and check it using SqliteBrowser [Link](http://master-gtu.blogspot.in/2012/10/download-sqlite-database-browser.html) , make sure you insert data is correct or not and then fetch data using some id and check it

Comment: Yes, i have done that and the data is coming in as pointed in my question above. Still doesnt tell me why the select query should give me wrong data and not the one stored in my SQLite.